# Having trouble class

Tags: css

I'm new to the CSS and I think I'm asking a dumb question,
in the CSS

I wrote this first=

```
input.text, input[type="text"], input.password, input[type="password"], textarea, select { border: 1px solid black; }
```

and this I wrote afterwards=

```
.HTMLWidget-2 input.text, input[type="text"], input.password, input[type="password"], textarea, select .subscribeInput { background-color: grey; }
```

and everything came out like the second one.
Thanks.

Comment: if you have both lines running, the second line is most certainly going to overwrite the first line. Most of first and second line seem to refer to the same classes and elements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. so all I have to do is move the first to be afterwards? Is there any other I can do this?

Comment: No, in this case it won't matter what order you put them in, anything matching the selectors `input[type="text"], input.password, input[type="password"], textarea` will get both the border and the background. If that's not what you want, you need to identify what you do want by referring to your HTML and writing a more specific selector.  Also those two properties are not mutually exclusive--if you wanted to remove the border, you'd have to explicitly do so.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is basically equivalent to:

```
select { border: 1px solid black; }

.HTMLWidget-2 input.text, 
select .subscribeInput { background-color: grey; }

input[type="text"], 
input.password, 
input[type="password"], 
textarea{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: grey
}
```

If you want only inputs in `.HTMLWidget-2` to have the background it needs to be in every selector, ex:

```
input.text, 
input[type="text"], 
input.password, 
input[type="password"], 
textarea, 
select {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.HTMLWidget-2 input.text, 
.HTMLWidget-2 input[type="text"], 
.HTMLWidget-2 input.password, 
.HTMLWidget-2 input[type="password"], 
.HTMLWidget-2 textarea, 
.HTMLWidget-2 select {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Though as I recall...IE7 (I think) and IE6 won't change the default `select` border.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are giving more importance to your selector.

```
.HTMLWidget-2 input.text
```

is more specific than

```
input.text
```

I recommend you have a look at the W3 specification
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity